# How to find the position of each array object using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How can i return array position of each object in an array.

## code

```
let targets = [1.2, 2.3, 3.5];
let targetUpdatedOn = [2018-07-06, 2018-07-06, 2018-07-06];
let liveCoinPrice = 1.3;

let targets_hit = targets.filter(function(target_value) {
  return liveCoinPrice >= target_value;
});

This what is done to find array position.

targets_hit.forEach(function(key) { 

   if(targetUpdatedOn[key] === undefined){ 
       console.log(targetUpdatedOn); 
    } 
}
```

I want to return array position of each targets_hits . Any help would be thankful.

Comment: What is the value of `targetUpdatedOn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this.

```
targets_hit.forEach((item, index) => {
    console.log(item, index); // Item and index
    console.log(index) // Index only
});
```

The `forEach` method callback has 3 parameters.

1. Current Value
2. Index (Optional)
3. Array being traversed (Optional)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 3):

This is how you find position of each array object using [`array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in JavaScript:

```js
let targets = [1.2, 2.3, 3.5];

targets.forEach((element, index) => {
    console.log(`Object is ${element} and it's position is ${index}`);
});
```